# jQuery swap text when open

Tags: jquery

I have 3 paragraphs of text on a welcome message. For devices below a certain width I need to show only the first and hide the other 2 with a button the slide down and show the other text.

I have it working great BUT the text before opening reads 'Open to read more' and i want the text to say 'Close to read less' when the text content is being show.

My code is below, I'm learning jQuery so am sure there is a much better way of doing things but at least I'm trying.

I'm using it to identify the first paragraph, wrap all others in a box, then add another for the button which uses a stored text. Then toggle the panel open and shut on clicks.

```
$('body.home .landing.left p:first').addClass('first');
 if($(window).width() < 768) { 

   var open  = "Open to read more";
   var close = "Close to read less";

   $('body.home .landing.left p').not('.first').wrapAll('<div class="more"></div>');

   $('body.home .landing.left .more').wrap('<div class="moreCont"></div>');

   $('.moreCont').append('<a class="viewMore">'+ open + '</a>');

    $('.moreCont a.viewMore').click(function() {
        $('.moreCont .more').slideToggle();

    });
}
```

The a.viewMore button is the one the text is being shown on

Comment: Please do this with CSS and not js...

Comment: Hi Dominik, do you think using a :before {content:"Open to read more"} and just toggle classes changing the content?

Comment: Yes that would be more semantic and better manageable. And I'm not sure I understand but you can toggle the text with media queries as well. A js listener on browser resize is very expensive and I would try to avoid it

Comment: also your first js line is the same as `:first-child()` no?

Comment: The first line is to add a class to first p then I use line 5 to select other paragraphs that don't have that class to wrap. I suppose I can remove and use not:first. My browser resize listener do you mean the if is less than width of 768px? I need to run this function and wrap only for mobiles. A better way perhaps??? Willing to learn!

Comment: Feel free to tick the "answer" box if the below answer helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with as little js as possible. Just because the media breakpoints are already built into CSS.

I made you a very bare-minimum working example. I would end up possibly adding the button with JS and check with CSS if js is available (`js` and `no-js` classes on the `html`) before hiding it in mobile just so you have a no-js fallback for when something goes wrong(or god-forbid js is off).
Animations can be added too.

Hope it helps.

**JS**

```
$('.js-toggle').on('click', function() {
    var $main = $('main');
    var _isOpen = $main.hasClass('is-open');

    if( _isOpen ) {
        $main.removeClass('is-open');
        $(this).text('Open to read more')
    }
    else {
        $main.addClass('is-open');
        $(this).text('Close to read less')
    }
});
```

**CSS** (compiled)

```
p {
    display: none;
}
.is-open p {
    display: block;
}
p:first-child {
    display: block;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 786px) {
    p {
        display: block;
    }
    button {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

## CodePen

http://codepen.io/dominikwilkowski/pen/yNPxYd